# Meeting Axel in Super Overlord Descent

Tags: disgaea-3

I am in the extra chapter "Super Overlord Descent". I just got Marona, and I am well aware that Axel is the next one to meet. I already talked with all the people in the Academy. However, I can't find the bill to meet Axel in the Homeroom.

What am I missing?